# Prove that there exists $b \in B$ such that $d(a, b) = d(a, B)$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am currently taking an introductory real analysis course which corresponds roughly to the first half of Rudin.

The following problems have me absolutely stumped:

1. Let $B \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be nonempty and compact with $a \in B^C$. Prove that there exists $b \in B$ such that $d(a, b) = d(a, B$).
2. Let $B \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be nonempty and closed with $a \in B^C$. Prove that there exists $b \in B$ such that $d(a, b) = d(a, B$).
3. In this part, we consider the metric space $\mathbb{Q}$ (usual metric). I want to find a nonempty closed subset $B \in \mathbb{Q}$ and a rational number $a \in B^C$. such that there is no $b \in B$ for which $d(a, b) = d(a, B$.

On notation: By $d(a, B)$ we mean the smallest distance from $a$ to any point in $B$. That is, $d(a, B) = \inf \{d(a, b) \mid b \in B \}$.

**My thoughts on the problem:**

In parts (a) and (b), we are working in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and as such receive some nice properties. For example, since $B \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ is compact, it is evident that $B$ is closed and bounded. Thus part (a) follows directly from part (b).

However, I feel that this is the wrong approach since (a) is asked before (b). Furthermore, I have not made any nontrivial progress on part (b).

In part (c), we are showing that the statements in (a) and (b) do not hold in a general metric space. In particular, (b) does not hold in the metric space $X=\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual metric. This leads me to believe that I need to choose a $B$ that has rational endpoints. My first instinct is to guess $B=(\sqrt 2, \sqrt{3}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ which is nonempty and closed. My intuition tells me that we cannot find a number outside this interval with minimal distance to $B$ because if there was such a number, we could find another rational in between (by the density of real numbers). However, I have yet to be able to formalize this idea rigourously.

*Note that I chose to include all 3 subparts in this one question as I feel that they are extremely related.*

Comment: You know that B is closed. What can you say about closure and limit points? Is d(a,B) a limit point?

Comment: @JohnDouma Since $B$ is closed it contains its limit points. As for whether $d(a, B)$ is a limit point, I am not sure. I would need to show that every neighbourhood of $d = d(a, B)$ contains a point $x \neq d$.

Comment: Suppose a neighborhood of the inf didn't contain any points in B. Can you construct an open cover for B which doesn't have a finite subcover?

Comment: @JohnDouma I'm not quite sure how I would do that unfortunately ...

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that continuous functions on compact sets have minima and maxima? If so, Define $f_a(b)=d(a,b)$. This is a continuous function and has a minimum which must be equal to $d(a,B)$. Then for part b, take the intersection of a closed ball of radius $d(a,B)+1$ and $B$. This is a compact set and so part a applies.

Comment: @JohnDouma I would not be able to use the extreme value theorem without proof, I believe.

Comment: @MathMajor did you manage to find an answer without using convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can show that $d(a,B)$=inf$\{d(a,b): b\in B \}$ is a limit point of B then the fact that $B$ is closed means that the inf is in $B$.

Let $r = d(a, B)$

Construct a sphere of radius $r$ around $a$. Since $r$ is the greatest lower bound of distances from $a$ to points in $B$ we know that no points of $B$ lie in the interior of our sphere. Given $\epsilon\gt 0$, Construct a sphere of radius $r+\epsilon$ around $a$. Since $r$ is the greatest lower bound, there must be at least one point of $B$ in the interior of this sphere. Since we chose $\epsilon$ with no other properties than it being positive, this is true for all $\epsilon\gt 0$.

Therefore, we can construct a sequence of points $\{b_n\}$ such that $b_i\in B$ and $d(a,b_i)\lt r+\frac{1}{i}$. This sequence has a subsequence that converges to a point $b\in B$ and $d(a,b)\le r$. But we also know that $d(a,b)\ge r$ so $d(a,b)=r$.

For part 3, let $B=\{q\in\mathbb Q: 0\le q^2\le 2\}$ and let $a=2$. You should be able to see that no element of $B$ is going to have the desired property because $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. Is there any chance you can provide a method without mention of sequences? This topic has not yet been covered.

Comment: My original idea was to construct an open cover. In other words, you still argue that all of the spheres of radius $r+\epsilon$ contain points of $B$ but instead of using a sequence you assume no points of $B$ intersect the sphere of radius $r$. Then the collection of open sets which are the complements of closed balls around $a$ cover $B$ but since there is an element of $B$ in every open set, there can be no finite subcover.

Comment: @MathMajor Also, the above proof doesn't quite work for non-compact closed sets because we used the fact that a sequence has a convergent subsequence. I am sure we are missing something simple so maybe someone else can jump in with something better.