# Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ that is bounded an closed. and $a \in B^c$, then there exists $b \in B$ s.t. $d(a,b) = d(a,B)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I found the same question here:[Prove that there exists $b \in B$ such that $d(a, b) = d(a, B)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491696/prove-that-there-exists-b-in-b-such-that-da-b-da-b)

The writer was working through the same problem as I am but it seems like no solution was found for just a closed set.

My point of confusion is how to prove this for non-compact but closed sets. Essentially a set that is not bounded. Any hints would be appreciated to construct this proof.

Comment: Actually, the result there does cover the case that the set $B$ is just closed. I wrote an answer before I looked over there, and I'll leave it up to show how you can use the result for the compact case to extend to the case where $B$ is just closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be the ball centered around $a$ with radius $2d(a,B).$ Then $\overline{R}\cap B$ is nonempty, closed, and bounded. Then it is compact, so we may apply the result for that case to find $b\in\overline{R}\cap B$ such that $d(a,b)=d(a,\overline{R}\cap B).$ Since $b\in\overline{R}\cap B,$ $b\in B,$ and we observe that for any point $c\in B\cap R^{c},$ $d(a,c)\geq 2d(a,B),$ so $$d(a,b)=\inf_{c\in\overline{R}\cap B}d(a,c)=\inf_{c\in B}d(a,c)=d(a,B).$$

Comment: Thank you so much. How do we know that $\bar{R} \cap B $ is necessarily bounded?

Comment: To the proposer:   $\overline R \cap B$ is a subset of $\overline  R. $ The def'n of a bounded  set $S$ is:  $\exists r>0\;\exists  p\;\forall q\in S\;(d(q,p)\leq r).$  So $\overline R$ is bounded: Let $p=a$ and $r=2d(a,B).$

Comment: I see.. that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Though it is not clear to me how $d(a,c) > 2d(a,B)$. Isn't $B \cap R^c$ just the partition of $B$?

Comment: By definition, $R=\{c\in\mathbb{R}^{k}:d(a,c) <2d(a,B)\}.$ Thus, for any $c\in B\cap R^{c},$ $c\in R^{c},$ and therefore $d(a,c)\geq 2d(a,B).$

Answer (score 0):

The result does not extend to unbounded closed sets. For example, let k=2, B={(x,y):x>0,y>0 and xy=1}. Let a be the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: My example is erroneous. I have posted a proof.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sequence $\{b_n\}$ such that $||b_n-a||$ converges to d(a,B). Since $||b_n-a||$ is bounded it follows that $||b_n||$ is also bounded. Hence $\{b_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence. If b is the limit of such a subsequence then d(a,b)=d(a,B).

Comment: I'm curious to know whether there is a way to do this without using the convergence of the sequence. I understand the proof, but at that point in Rudin, you'd have not covered convergence. I'm assuming the above proof shows that way though.